# Usage of base class type pointer to the derived type object

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Suppose we have the following code:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void print()
    {
        cout << "I'm base" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void print() override 
    {
        cout << "I'm derived" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base* b = new Derived();
    b->print();
}
```

What I cannot understand is: what are the benefits of creating an object in this way and not simply:

```
Derived* d = new Derived();
```

Is it only used when we want to access fields and properties of the base class, but for virtual functions use the overriden ones from the derived class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your particular code, there is no real benefit in using the first method over the second. However, consider when you have two (or more) derived classes and want to use a common pointer to an instance of one of those classes, the actual type depending on some (run-time) condition. That's when such polymorphism shows its usefulness.

Something like the following:

```cpp
int main()
{
    Base* b;
    std::cout << "Enter 1 or 2: ";
    int choice;
    std::cin >> choice;
    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            b = new Derived1();
            break;
        case 2:
            b = new Derived2();
            break;
        default:
            b = new Base();
            break;
    }
    b->print();

    // ... other stuff to do with your polymorphic instance ...

    delete b; // ... and don't forget to delete it when you're done!
    return 0;
}
```

I'll leave it as 'an exercise for the reader' to provide the definitions of the `Derived1` and `Derived2` classes.

Comment: Don't forget to add a `virtual` destructor to `Base`, and then call `delete b;` when you are done using the object.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Indeed - another 'exercise for the reader'.

Comment: @RemyLebeau true, I just wanted to make the example as simple as possible to point at the specific question that I asked.